# passing parameter to mysql command dynamically and column relating

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I have 3 tables 1>disease_table [columns=] (disease_id,disease_name)2>symptom_table [columns=] (symptom_id,symptom_name)3>disease_symptom [columns=] (disease_id,symptom_id)

I want it to display disease name based on symptoms entered by user through checkboxes which can be any number of symptoms. So I know that disease_id will be primary key in disease_table, but I don't understand how to relate disease_id,symptom_id in disease_symptom table.Also I have something like this in mind

```
select disease_name,disease_id 
from disease_symptom ds
InnerJoin symptom_table s on ds.symptom_id=s.symptom_id
InnerJoin disease_table d on d.disease_id=s.disease_id
where s.symptom_name in('checkbox1.text','checkbox2.text',.... and so on)
```

So basically what I want to know is how to relate disease_id,symptom_id in disease_symptom table and how to pass dynamically adjusted number of parameter (user could select 3 checkboxes , sometimes 4 ,5 etc)...Thanks

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework?

Comment: @AndrewPaes no its in asp.net basic not fancy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct SQL:

```
select
  d.name
  , d.disease_id 
from Disease d
inner join DiseaseSympton ds on ds.disease_id = d.disease_id
inner join Sympton s on s.sympton_id = ds.sympton_id
where s.name in ('Fever')
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d85fe7/6)

Getting checkbox values dynamically ( I couldn't test MySQL Conns ):

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Linq;


public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var chBoxList= new CheckBoxList();
        chBoxList.Items.Add(new ListItem("Headache", "1"));
        chBoxList.Items.Add(new ListItem("Fever", "2"));
        chBoxList.Items.Add(new ListItem("Nause", "3"));

        chBoxList.Items[1].Selected = true;
        chBoxList.Items[2].Selected = true;

        string symptons = String.Join(", ", chBoxList.Items.Cast<ListItem>()
                                      .Where(i => i.Selected)
                                      .Select(i => i.Text));

        Console.WriteLine(symptons);


        using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(...))
        {
            connection.Open();

            using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("select d.name , d.disease_id from Disease d inner join DiseaseSympton ds on ds.disease_id = d.disease_id inner join Sympton s on s.sympton_id = ds.sympton_id where s.name in ('@pSymptons');", connection))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pSymptons", symptons);

                using (MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        ...
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/H98IGR)

Comment: thanks for replying to my question. The mysql query works fine but the
    string symptons = String.Join(", ", chBoxList.Items.Cast<ListItem>()
                                      .Where(i => i.Selected)
                                      .Select(i => i.Text));
has error it says Error 5 The best overloaded method match for 'string.Join(string, string[])' has some invalid arguments 
tried using .ToArray() at end but it still doesn't produce any result

Comment: Did you declare "using System.Linq;"?

Comment: can you explain me that statement ("string symptons...")..what does it do..even after adding reference , it doesn't produce any result.
but sql query works absolutely fine

Comment: Hello, i got it now ..the output of that statement would be a comma seperated selected values from checkbox list. so now the question is how to pass these varying values into sql statement in place of @pSymptons

Comment: Well, I'll explain in a very simple way. In this snip it is captured all items within the checkbox list, where they are casted for the ListItem type whose checkbox is selected. So it's taken the "text" value of the selected checkbox and they are "lined up" and attributed to a string being separated by a comma. See the example in the link I put in response "Net Fiddle"

Comment: yup i got it thanks but now how can I pass that obtained string into sql statement near "in" clause

Comment: In SQL statemnet we have a holding parameter @pSymptons this will be replaced by "cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pSymptons", symptons);"

Comment: yes I get that ..but as I said in my question ..it may happen that user could select 1 or 2 or all checkbox for mentioning symptom so that will be varying how to pass that varying variable to sql stmt.?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103197/discussion-between-panman-and-andrew-paes).